# An issue with src(unknown) - broken image in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-chrome

I am having a really strange behavior in Chrome when I try to display images.

I see some little badges with breaking images like that:
[image]
This is just broken image picture.

It didn't work like that in chrome before.

I use some javascript code to handle not found images:

```
//This script will be loaded in head section of the page
function fixBrokenImage(element) {
    element.onerror = '';
    element.src = '';
}
```

And in HTML:

```
<img src="~/Image?getById=@Model" onerror="fixBrokenImage(this)"/>
```

However, it only works in Chrome for the first time when I do Clear Cache and Hard Refresh and does not work in subsequent normal refreshes

It is ashamed to say but it works in IE and Edge which feels a little bit funny.

Do you know maybe how can I fix it in Chrome.
I am using version: Version 63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Why don't you just do something like `this.style.display='none'` to hide broken images?

Comment: Please define "it doesn't work". What do you expect as a result, and what is the result instead.

Comment: @JeremyThille, I don't use this.style.display='none' as there is some css style which modifies it and does not work for some cases

Comment: @Teemu, I expect to set src='' but it is src(unknown). Generally, I expect to not have broken image in both scenarios. That issue might be related to the recent Chrome releases.

Comment: Browsers can't find empty src (it triggers an error too), and actually the behavior of showing "failed icon" is correct. Add an (empty) `alt` attribute to show an alternative description if the image can't be found, instead of setting src to empty.

Comment: @Teemu. That might be correct according to the specification. In my real case I just call MVC action to the the file. If there is no file I return NotFoundResult. So, onerror is handling that fine if I refresh Chrome with hard refresh but does not work when I do normal refresh. That's wired. It works on IE and Edge

Comment: The treatment of the broken image sources has been varying accros browsers during times, sometimes the broken image is shown, sometimes it is not. An empty `alt` is the simplest way to hide a broken image. You can set `alt` to empty in the error handler, if you otherwise need it (actually leaving it out would be invalid HTML).

Comment: Yes, you are right. It helped in Chrome. Adding empty attribute alt='' in html element helped

Comment: Is this https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/3a369b4b3097687b8b8f122f73b7fa8f7e412a3e ?

Comment: Yes, that might be that change:  
Changed from bool no_src_specified = !element.hasAttribute(srcAttr) || element.getAttribute(srcAttr).IsNull();
To:
bool no_src_specified = !element.hasAttribute(srcAttr) ||
                          element.getAttribute(srcAttr).IsNull() ||
                          element.getAttribute(srcAttr).IsEmpty();

Answer (score 1):

You can use this javascript code like this, you forgot to put ***alt*** attribute:

```
function fixBrokenImage(element) {
    element.onerror = '';
    element.src = '';
    element.alt = 'image not found'
}
```

Comment: Another alternative is:
<img src="~/Image?getById=@Model" onerror="this.style.display='none';/>

`function fixBrokenImage(element) {
    element.onerror = '';
    element.src = '';
    element.style.display = 'none';
}`

Comment: Thanks @Alex, adding empty alt="" to html element did the job. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it working by adding empty attribute to the html element:

```
<img src="~/Image?getById=@Model" onerror="fixBrokenImage(this)" alt=""/>
```

Thanks @Teemu for your suggestions which eventually made that code work on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

if you are using php then `esc_url($url)` will solve it, esc_url function solves the problem or just use `URL.createObjectURL(url)` simply in Js